# Deleting jpa entity on One-To-One relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables that are related to one-to-one relationship:

```
public class Person {

  // some other fields

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "image_id")
  private FileInfoModel image;

}

public class FileInfoModel {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @NotBlank
  private String name;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "size_in_bytes")
  private Long size;

  // some other fields

}
```

When I tried to delete the image with the repository: **repository.deleteById(file.getId());**
I get the following error:

> update or delete on table "file_info" violates foreign key constraint
>   "fk_image" on table "person".

Is there any way to set the Person table image_id field to null when deleting FileInfo from the repository? I know I can set person.setImage(null) and save it and then delete the file but I think there could be an easier way with fewer steps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an JPQL query to automatically set all Persons with that image to a null image before deleting it. Roughly:

```
update Person p set p.image = null where p.image = :image
```

I'd recommend to be explicit about this and not implement some magic via listeners or similar as you'd generally not expect something to be deleted when references to it still exist.